# Can I draw multiple connectors on single edge of a rectangle in Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio

I need to draw a diagram where multiple connectors come out of single edge of a shape (rectangle for example).

**Can it be done without losing the connection between the connectors and the rectangles?**

In other words - can I change the number of "attachment points" for the edge of a shape?

This is how Visio normally behaves:

[image]

This is what I need to draw (I have done this by copying connectors and moving them manually to desired place, so they lost connections):

[image]

And this is what happens when I move one of rectangles.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the Connection Point tool (Home/Tools)? It looks like an X.

Select your shape, click this, and then press CTRL & click where you want the new connection point.

Comment: I thought this question was answered...  Weird. So this "X" button does the job. Before I found an answer I have never tried to click it or even hover over it to see what it does, because it looks like a button that deletes something :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but you need to use the **Snap & Glue** menu to allow the connectors to glue to shape geometry or shape vertices.

How to find this is at:
[Adjust snap strength or turn snap off](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/adjust-snap-strength-or-turn-snap-off-94dadb54-f6b1-45f5-9795-c3ec2a1f8671)